# Manually expire low level cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I'm using the following low-level caching for the five most recent news articles in my Rails application:

```
@recent_news = Rails.cache.fetch("recent_news", :expires_in => 1.hour) do
  News.order("created_at desc").limit(5)
end
```

Is there a way to keep this query cached until a new news article is created? I was thinking of manually expiring the cache using an observer, but wasn't sure if there was a way to actually do this, e.g:

```
class NewsObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create
    #expire recent_news cache
  end
end
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can manually expire the cache using the `.delete` method:

```
Rails.cache.delete("recent_news")
```

Comment: I would also expand your fetch command to include: `(race_condition_ttl: 10)`  This will fetch a new set for @recent news by running one query when the expire time hits. Instead of possibly running many queries when it expires before the cache is set.